# Why are metal oxides basic and non-metals' acidic or neutral

Tags: acid-base

Recently I came across the fact: *Metal oxides basic and non-metals' acidic or neutral.*

Searching for it, partly my query is solved, as I found:

Metal oxides or $\ce{O2-}$ forms $\ce{OH-}$ after hydrolysis in the following reaction so metal oxides are basic in aqeous solutions.
$$\ce{O2- + 2H2O->4OH-}$$

I think this might happen as metal form ionic compunds and non-metals form covalent and some of them may not even react tus neutral.

I've got only a little $5\%$ of the exact reason, therefore I wish if someone could explain the whole process/fact. I considered Arhenius concept.

**Note** My question is partly answered [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/why-does-polonium-form-acidic-oxides), but is not satisfactory.

Comment: >but is not satisfactory. || what the answer you linked lacks?

Comment: So how is this story goes with water?

Comment: related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28132/how-is-charge-density-a-useful-measure-of-polarising-power-and-polarisability, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19763/why-is-pbcl%e2%82%84-covalent, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/hardness-and-softness-are-terms-used-to-describe-which-aspect-of-acidic-behaviou

Answer (score 3):

We have learnt that metallic oxides are basic nature. This is because the oxides of metals like $\ce{MgO}$ or $\ce{CaO}$ or $\ce{Na2O}$ form hydroxides in their aqueous solutions.
For example:
$$\ce{K2O + H2O -> 2KOH}$$
$$\ce{MgO + H2O -> Mg(OH)2}$$

But when non-metallic oxides dissociate into their constituent ions in water, they give $\ce{H+}$ ions in their aqueous solutions forming acids
For example:
$$\ce{CO2 + H2O -> H2CO3}$$
$$\ce{SO3 + H2O -> H2SO4}$$

Comment: This just restates information in a previous answer and the equations are also unbalanced. Perhaps you could clean this up a little and add some more detail.

Comment: I have improved the formatting of your post using $\LaTeX$. For more information on how to do this yourself please see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-we-correct-math-formatting/444#444). Additionally, you can visit [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27198/latex-mathjax-help) for more assistance.

Comment: so they are acidic because they **form** acids? Sorry I dont know much about Arrehinius definition...only know the Brownsted Lowry one

Answer (score 0):

Metal oxides like $\ce{CaO}$ and $\ce{Na2O}$ react with water and give hydroxides:

$\ce{CaO + H2O <=> Ca(OH)2}$

$\ce{Na2O + H2O <=> 2 NaOH}$

While non-metal oxides like $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{SO2}$ react with water and give acids:

$\ce{CO2 + H2O <=> H2CO3 <=> H+ + HCO3-}$

$\ce{SO2 + H2O <=> H2SO3 <=> H+ + HSO3-}$

Comment: can you use technical terms, thermodynamics, kinetics, bonding theories or other theoretical explanations?

Comment: It still didn't explain why.