# Classification of Oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

There is a way to classify oxides according to their behavior where we have the following categories: Acidic, Basic, Amphoteric and Neutral. But is there a way of classifying the oxides according to their chemical bond?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/how-to-decide-acidic-or-basic-nature-of-oxides?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The classification we use to distinguish bonds in other chemical compounds will obviously be valid for the classification of oxides.

They can be classified as covalent or ionic.